# How to play a rtmp video stream in a native android application?

Tags: java, android

I am in a project where I have to play video streams of the tv channels from the link. But the problem is I have to play the videos in a native app not in a webview. As far as I did is just implemented an API called `VITAMIO` which helps a lot to play http, mms etc protocols, but fails to play the RTMP video. I also researched and found that the basic android `videoview` also fails to play RTMP, so I just want to know that is there any API available or is there any way to play video in a native android application which will support RTSP, RTMP, MMS, HTTP etc?

Comment: Have you got native solution?, how to play RTMP live stream using native component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vitamio, this is plugin native app playback stream rmpt,http,...very well.It work fine for me. I think you check link channel by VLC.

Comment: I used vitamio but it doesnt support rtmp, can you please provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

RTMP is flash only.  Chances are the VITAMIO player will work on some devices and not at all on others.  I'm not sure if you are using the plugin version or the licensed version of their player. My interaction with it was small as I wasnt really impressed (at the time...I will go back and try again later this year)

What you can do:

1. Create/Use your own flash player
2. Create an activity that has a webview in it
3. Add detecting of the flash plugin on android.
4. have the webview load up your flash swf file

here is some code to detect flash and load a url if it has it:

```
    String url = "http://www.example.com/movie.swf";

    try {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo flash_ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0);
        int flash_version = pm.getPackageInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0).versionCode;
        if (flash_ai != null && flash_version != 0 && flash_version >= 103000000) {
            flashInstalled = true;
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException ex) {
        flashInstalled = false;
    }
    if (!flashInstalled) {
        displayNeedFlashDialog();

    } else {
        WebView wvBrowser = new WebView(this);
        wvBrowser.requestFocus();
        wvBrowser.setClickable(true);
        wvBrowser.clearCache(true);
        wvBrowser.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        wvBrowser.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        wvBrowser.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        wvBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            }

            ;
        });
        setContentView(wvBrowser, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        wvBrowser.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Comment: But videoview doesnt support rtmp protocol

Comment: oh crap,  I read all this wrong. I mistakingly read it as "rtsp". So sorry.

Comment: So do you have any Idea about RTMP?

Comment: setContentView(wvBrowser, lp);
What is LP here?

Comment: your code looks interesting and may work, but as it is not so described I couldnt implement it, can you please say it in details? please

Comment: You gave 4 procedure, here you have given the last three details, but can you explain about the number one

1. Create/Use your own flash player